# User not staying logged into one of sub sites in multisite after SSL

Tags: multisite, login, ssl

I am not sure what is going on but I have a multisite that has user sync turned on. I recently added SSL certs to all of the site URLs and after installation one of my sites will not keep a user logged in.

You can actually log into the main site and visit three of the sites as that user but the 4th site when I get there I am not logged in and I can actually log in as another user if I wanted on that site.

This all started after I added my SSL cert.

Can I check the cookie info (not sure what to look for) to see why this is happening?

Any ideas would help pulling my hair out here.

Comment: What is user sync?

Comment: When a user logs into one site if they visit the rest of the sites they remain logged in.

Comment: For the 4th website, make sure the site & admin address are set as https too

Comment: @Denoteone is this a descriptive phrase or the feature of a plugin? Be crystal clear so that people don't get confused or misunderstand, I run multiple multisite installs and there is now option named user sync in WP